# segmentation fault when trying to run logstalgia

Tags: logs

I just installed *Logstalgia* package via `apt-get` on Ubuntu 14.04 server, when I try to run it with

```
root@server$ logstalgia production-default.log
```

The shell returns

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: As this is clearly a bug, I recommend you to take this up with the [maintainer](https://launchpad.net/~statik).

Comment: Have a graphgical interface?, logstalgia need show window with complex graphics, have problem with drivers?, video does not support shaders?